# ejs how to render template later

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I wanted to create a one-page only based website. the problem is, how to I render a template later?

also, how to render a specific post?

eg:

```
<!-- situation 1-->
<% include ../_header %>
<div width="40%">
  <% include ../menu %>  <!-- lots of post, once clicked will become situation 2 -->
</div>
<% include ../_footer %>

<!-- situation 2-->
<% include ../_header %>
<div width="40%">
  <% include ../menu %>
</div>
<div width="60%">
  <% include ../posts %>
</div>
<% include ../_footer %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using nodejs, and express, you will have two routes:

`router.get '/posts' (req, res) -> res.render('posts_template')`

`router.get '/posts/:post_id' (req, res) -> res.render('post_template')`

As you can see, you have two different routes and templates for displaying posts and a single post.

You will use `layouts`, have a `post_template` that defines only a post:

`File: post_template.ejs`

```
<% layout('layout') %>

<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p><%= body %></p>
```

And you will have a layout template for this post template:

`File: layout_template.ejs`

```
<h1>Posts list </h1>
<%= body %>
```

Now the `post_template` will be *nested* inside the `layout_template`, where the `<%= body %>` is.

Comment: the only problem is I dont know hwo to render them without going to next page

Comment: my question is, is that anyway to use specific js/html/ejs code to link <a href="some link">HERE</a> and load that template to <div id="someoutputpost"/>?

Comment: @user232436 look you don't understand, that's exactly what layouts are for. in your case, `situation 1` is your template, and it has a `<%= body %>` ejs tag, that says 'render my child here'. when you use the layout you specify in your `post` template and the body of the post will be loaded into the body of the layout. work these out and accept the answer asap.

Comment: sorry, you are right, something is wrong with template (too complicated ejs) :/